# Qt - No matching function to call connect

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to perform a classic connect in Qt, which I have done like a thousand times. But for some reason unknown to me, I cant right now: I get the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'gameView::connect(QComboBox*&, const char*, gameLogic*&, const char*)'
     connect(_dropdown, SIGNAL(activated(int)), _model, SLOT(resize(int)));
                                                                         ^
```

My code is as follows:
(gameview.h)

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QVector>
#include <QTime>
#include "gamelogic.h"

class gameView : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
...
        QComboBox*_dropdown;

...
        gameLogic* _model;

...

        explicit gameView(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~gameView();


    };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

(gameview.cpp)

```
#include "gameview.h"

gameView::gameView(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    _model = new gameLogic();
...
    _dropdown = new QComboBox();
...

    _dropdown->addItem("4");
    _dropdown->addItem("6");
    _dropdown->addItem("8");
    connect(_dropdown, SIGNAL(activated(int)), _model, SLOT(resize(int))); //error here
... 
}
```

(gamelogic.h)

```
#ifndef GAMELOGIC_H
#define GAMELOGIC_H

#include <QVector>
#include <QTimer>


class gameLogic
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    gameLogic();

...

public slots:
    void resize(int newn);


};

#endif // GAMELOGIC_H
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you talking about `gameView` or `gameLogic`? Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: `gameView` uses an instance of `gameLogic`, and I'm trying to make the connect in `gameView` but to a slot in `gameLogic`, that's why I included both. You can find the exact error message in my post. If I didn't understand your question correctly, please elaborate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently just adding `Q_OBJECT` is not enough. After making `gameLogic` into `class gameLogic : public QObject`, connect works.

Answer (score 3):

Your `gameLogic` class should inherit QObject, or the Qt signal/slot mechanism will not work. Try to change `class gameLogic` to `class gameLogic : public QObject`

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out in the end... Thought the `Q_OBJECT` should do the job.